# Performance query lenta

Tags: sql, query

Tenho um banco de dados que possui cerca de 3 teras e estou tendo problemas para otimizar algumas querys.

Nesse exemplo tenho 3 tabelas: Montadora, Carro e modelo.

E tenho esta query que demora cerca de 30m, todos os inner joins estão indexados e foi feita a query indo da menor tabela para a maior, as opções que estão de branco a 'ZZZ' são filtros que o usuário pode fazer na consulta então não posso alterá-los

Alguma dica de algo que pode estar errado ou uma outra maneira de fazer uma consulta.

```
Select * from Montadora m

INNER JOIN Carro c 
on c.codMontadora = m.codigo
and c.pais between '   ' AND 'ZZZZZ'
and c.estado between '   ' AND 'ZZZZZ'

INNER JOIN Modelo o
on o.codMontadora = c.codMontadora
and o.pais = c.pais
and o.estado = c.estado
and o.versao between '   ' AND 'ZZZZZ'
and o.cor between '   ' AND 'ZZZZZ'
and o.motor between '   ' AND 'ZZZZZ'

where 
m.codigo = 'GM'
```

Comment: Por que colocar critérios de seleção na condição de junção? Não seria melhor fazer a junção e então aplicar os critérios de seleção ou ainda, caso as condições impliquem numa redução substancial do número de registros, fazer um subselect aplicando os critérios de seleção e utilizar o resultado na junção?

Comment: Poderia paginar isso colocando um limit no select.

Comment: se você colocar um [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) antes do select você pode analisar onde está o gargalo.

Answer (score 0):

Consigo pensar em algumas poucas melhorias, basicamente:

1. **tire os `and` do `join`**; checar estas condições na junção aumenta
   muito a quantidade de validações na hora de juntar uma tabela a
   outra.
2. **pare de usar `between`**; é preferível usar `< >`.
3. **remova as validações desnecessárias**; você diz que existem *"filtros que o usuário pode fazer na consulta"*, então esses filtros podem vir ou não (e se não vêm, são validações desnecessárias).
4. **use códigos inteiros ao invés de *strings***; o código da montadora não é inteiro; além disso, vários campos poderiam ser tabelas referenciadas por código, o que diminuiria a perda na validação.

---

```
Select * 
FROM Montadora m
INNER JOIN Carro c ON c.codMontadora = m.codigo
INNER JOIN Modelo o ON o.codMontadora = c.codMontadora
WHERE m.codigo = 'GM'
  AND o.pais = c.pais
  AND o.estado = c.estado
  AND (c.pais >= @pais_ini AND c.pais <= @pais_fim)
  AND (c.estado >= @estado_ini AND c.estado <= @estado_fim)
  AND (c.versao >= @versao_ini AND c.versao <= @versao_fim)
  AND (c.cor >= @cor_ini AND c.cor <= @cor_fim)
  AND (c.motor >= @motor_ini AND c.motor <= @motor_fim)
```

A melhoria **4** é bem difícil de implementar, já que o banco está em produção; mas ele parece ter bastante falha no quesito *chave estrangeira* (OBS: falo isso sem ver a estrutura, apenas pela consulta que você trouxe).

Sendo assim, o ideal seria uma opção **5** que seria reformular a estrutura; apenas pra exemplificar, a *cor* deveria ser do `carro`, não do `modelo`.